# Cholesky Factorisation of a Matrix $A$ Given $A=LDL^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose you have a matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 2 \\ -1 & 1 & -1 \\2 & -1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}.$$ It can be shown that $A=LDL^T$, where $$L=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\ -1/2 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \ \ \text{and} \ \ D=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$ From this, how can we find the Cholesky factorisation $A=R^TR$? By definition, $R$ is an upper triangular matrix with positive diagonal entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very obviously from $A=LDL^T$ you get the factorisation $A=(LD^{1/2})(LD^{1/2})^T$ if $D$ has non-negative entries. Since the Cholesky-factorisation is unique if it exists and $D^{1/2}L$ is a triangular matrix with non-negative entries, it must be equal to the sought-after $R^T$.